# GETDATE() Function returns error "Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type."

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-insert, date-arithmetic

I have this insert statement that is supposed to add a row into this copied table. So my idea was to use the GetDate function to get today's date and for the other column to add 30 days tp it. When I got the error, I tried to convert it, but I don't fully understand what the issue is. The column uses smalldatetime format.

```
INSERT INTO InvoicecopyKJ VALUES 
    (32, 'AX-014-027', 
        GETDATE(), 
        4834.58, 0.00, 0.00, 2, 
        GETDATE() + 30,
        'NULL'
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `dateadd()`:

```
insert into invoicecopykj 
values (
    32, 
    'ax-014-027', 
    getdate(), 
    4834.58, 
    0.00, 
    0.00, 
    2, 
    dateadd(day, 30, getdate()),
    null
);
```

Notes

- `getdate()` returns the date *and time*. If you want the date part only, then use `convert(date, getdate())` instead
- presumably, you want a literal `null` as value in the last column rather than literal *string* `'null'` (the surrounding single quotes make it a string)
- it is a good practice to always enumerate the target columns for `insert`, like `insert into invoicecopykj (col1, col2, ...)`

Comment: Thanks! I tested it out and it worked. Yeah, I didn't know about ```dateadd```, but I'll try to be more aware of different functions in the future. But how would enumerating the columns work in this case?

Comment: @HubertH.: this means list the columns of your table `invoicecopykj`.